# Как сделать, чтобы заданные кнопки нажимались дольше 1 мсек?

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub TxtBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonBlue1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonBlue1.Click
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonGreen1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonGreen1.Click
        Timer1.Stop()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

        SendKeys.Send("{W}")
        SendKeys.Send("{D}")
        SendKeys.Send("{A}")
        SendKeys.Send("{E}")
        SendKeys.Send("{E}")
        SendKeys.Send("{S}")
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(3200)
        SendKeys.Send("{^}")
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
        SendKeys.Send("{^}")

    End Sub
    Private Function Form1_KeyDown(v As Object, keyEventArgs As KeyEventArgs) As Object
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте keybd_event и сможете сами контролировать задержку между нажатием и отжатием. Примеры в сети есть.

Comment: @VladD Хорошо, пару мин.